# subfolder or subdomain - Which one is the best?

Tags: website-design, directory

I'm creating a website for web creator, designer and video editor. I'm a multimedia integrator, so I'm doing almost everything related to media on the web or video. Whatever, on my portfolio I would like to add a photography section for my personal photos to show people that I love more than only web/video. Also, I draw a wireframe of what my photography page could look like and it will be really different from my original portfolio website I'm creating.

For example, my portfolio website has the nav menu on top, but the photography website will have the menu fixed on the left with a filter (to choose which picture you want to look at). Do you think I should put this photography section as "mywebsite.com/photogrpahy" or "photography.mywebsite.com"? I heard that sometimes SEO is weird with subdomain.

Also, thinking about adding two blogs in the futur. One for my work and one other for my travel and other personal stuffs. So I thought about :

mywebsite.com/blog ---> Work

blog.mywebsite.com ---> Travel/activities/etc.

What do you think about this?

Thank you

Comment: the best at what?

Answer (score 4):

When you create a subdomain, essentially it becomes an entirely different web site, so using subdomains makes sense when you talk about the fact that they are separate subjects, a different audience, and work and look different.

As an example, you have google.com, but for developers, there is developer.google.com. Each with their own topic and usage.

Answer (score 4):

1) Main domain name `mywebsite.com` is easier to read in address bar/URL if you use `mywebsite.com/blog` scheme compared to `blog.mywebsite.com`, so users to memorize your domain name better.

2) SEO doesn't really like subdomains because they distribute PageRank score comparing to one domain.

Comment: +1 for the SEO tip. Chances are, your blog is the only thing that will contribute search relevance. Taking that away from your portfolio is probably a bad thing. If you want to start an unrelated blog, then by all means you should have a different domain.

Comment: Sources for both points would be good.